# ConfigurationErrorsException: Unable to load type ... because it is not public

Tags: windows-services, app-config

I am trying to access a custom section of the app.config in a windows service application.

This is how I have defined the section

```
<Configurations>
 <configSections>
   <section name="SectionName" type="ClassName, AssemblyName"/>
 </configSections>
 <SectionName>...</SectionName>
</Configurations>
```

I get the following error

> An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for `SectionName`: Unable to load type '`ClassName`, `AssemblyName`, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it is not public.

What could be the possible reasons for this error?

Comment: Yes, the class is very much public.

Comment: and it is called ClassName in the AssemblyName namespace?

Comment: yes it is.
Anyway, I solved my problem. Was missing a default constructor. Sorry, my bad

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although the class existed and was publicly accessible, it was missing a default constructor.
Obviously the default constructor would be getting called internally at the time of parsing the config, and hence is a must for such classes, which are used in config sections.